# HTML export of Babel source block only results?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, html

I'm reading [this](https://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting-Code-Blocks.html), but I'm not seeing how to export *just* the results of a Babel source block. Every other combination seems possible but just results, i.e., suppress the code, show the results. My particular application is using gnuplot and tikz source blocks that I don't want to see in the html output, rather, just the graphs they've produced.

Comment: Doesn't `:exports results` work? Note the plurals.

Comment: I found and got rid of  `(setq org-export-babel-evaluate nil)` That was the culprit. How long have I been suffering under this tyranny?!

Comment: Marginal note: since Org 9.1 the name of the variable is `org-export-use-babel` with a default value of `t`. `org-export-babel-evaluate` is an alias for backward compatibility but it should be considered obsolete.